# Running a program in CentOS

Tags: centos7

I have a piece of software installed on CentOS 7.1 and I am trying to understand what this means:

```
[root@001 install]# bash niagarad_generic
Usage: naxd {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}
```

When I try to use naxd it tells me the command cannot be found. A little bit of a newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is a shell, an environment that runs programs in unix. niagarad_generic is a script being run. I guess the naxd is another program it runs, but it can't be found. Try running this

```
find / -name "naxd"
```

to see if it's on your drive.

The program requires parameters. Try this

```
bash niagarad_generic start
```

The "bash" part isn't usually required, this may work
    ./niagarad_generic start

"./" just means "current directory".

Leave a comment if this doesn't answer your question :)

Comment: Great, happy to help :) Please hit the little tick mark top to the left of my post to accept my answer.